# largest size for a randomness extractor

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, entropy, cryptography, algorithmic-randomness

I am not so expert in theoretical computer science, so sorry if the question is trivial, i just could not find it in literature.

Suppose we have a source $X$ with min-entropy $\ell$, the randomness extractor is defined as a function $f$ which satisfies the total variation $||f(X, R)-U_M||_{TV}\leq \epsilon$ where $R$ is an external randomness and $U_M$ is a uniform random variable over a set of $M$ points. My question is what is the largest value of $M$ for which we can have the extractor $f$ for source $X$?

Thanks

Comment: You may try cstheory.stackexchange.com